# App for Blackberry 10

Tags: feature-request, android-app, blackberry

I'm a BlackBerry user - I have a Z10 - and I've sideloaded the Stack Exchange android app onto it and it works perfectly. So I was wondering how hard could it be to simply change a few values in the app that tell Stack Exchange it is the Android app to Blackberry, then simply sumbit the apk to the BlackBerry World converter?

Being an Blackberry fan, I seriously believe that the BlackBerry market share is now on the increase and will continue this way. So maybe this would be a good thing?

Comment: Hahahaha! Great trolling!

Comment: Wait....blackberry is still around? What next the palm pilot return?

Comment: Yeah, I was just trying for another hat... the Android app does not work on a SiMKo3 (Android 4.2) but wonderfully on the Blackberry Z10 (after having duckduckgo'd for the APK). And it is nicely done/usable. I did not even sideload, I just downloaded and installed the apk file.

Comment: Actually I didn't sideload either - just installed the apk from Snap (BB10 unofficial version of Play Store) - but users on anything earlier that 10.2.1 would have to sideload - and I know it works

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt it's as simple as you make it sound.

Don't forget the app will need to be tested before release and it will need to be supported by SE afterwards.

I'm not sure the slight gains of having such an app would compensate for the **actual** effort it would take to make and maintain it.

Comment: Yes I can understand that - but I thought more than anything I would just say that it works on BB10